# How to normalize a Date filed into UTC format (2019-10-29T02:20:30.45Z) [this is not a duplicate question ,Please read the whole question once]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python development .

Current I am pulling a date from an API call eg = 10-29-2019 02:32 (mm-dd-yyyy  %H,%M)
Note : I don't have seconds here, so I would like to add 00 for seconds

I want this to be normalized to ISO 8601 UTC format 2019-10-29T02:20:30.45Z .

I have been trying multiple things suggested by various platform but I have not been able to get the "45Z" part. I know that 45 indicates microseconds.

Here is closest thing I came to :

```
local = pytz.timezone ("Asia/Kolkata")
    datetime_without_tz = datetime.datetime.strptime("2015-02-14 12:34:56", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    datetime_with_tz = local.localize(datetime_without_tz, is_dst=None) # No daylight saving time
    datetime_in_utc = datetime_with_tz.astimezone(pytz.utc)
    x=datetime_in_utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')#if i print here 2019-10-28 21:02:00 UTC+0000
    print (datetime.datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z").isoformat()) #output :2019-10-28T21:02:00+00:00
```

Issue with this is :

1. Not able to date variable i.e datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
2. Not able to get the UTC format 'Z' part

Could anyone please let me know how can I get it into the above mentioned format please.

Comment: Your API does not deliver any seconds, so what do you want to put as seconds in your output. Please also include what you have tried so far

Comment: In the ISO 8601 format example you provide the *45* does not represents seconds but microseconds.

Comment: @YannickGuéhenneux sorry my bad have changed it now

Comment: @FlyingTeller have made the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the same part of the code as follows to display in the format

```
local = pytz.timezone ("Asia/Kolkata")
datetime_without_tz = datetime.datetime.strptime("2015-02-14 12:34:56", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
datetime_with_tz = local.localize(datetime_without_tz, is_dst=None)
print(datetime_with_tz.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ %Z%z'))
>>> 2015-02-14T12:34:56Z IST + offset
```

to convert to the time zone specified we can use

```
datetime_in_utc = datetime_with_tz.astimezone(pytz.utc)
print (datetime.datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z")
```